# Prevent data entry if inclusion criteria not met

Tags: logic, branch, criteria, redcap

I'd like to know how to prevent REDCap to let the operator enter data if inclusion criteria ( in a clinical trial or EHR study are not met ?

Are there a sort of  branching logic or anything else ?

for instance, there are 3 yes now questions, if all are yes, then the next instrument could be filled , if not all conditions are met, show a message ( that not all criteria are met) and **prevent data entry**.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically show a warning to the operator that the subject is excluded due to some factor, with a descriptive text field with branching logic (where 0 encodes 'no'): `[q1] = 0 or [q2] = 0 or [q3] = 0`.

There is also an external module called Form Render Skip Logic (FRSL) that allows you to define the logic controlling the flow between forms (whereas functions like survey queue do not work for forms), and thus only proceed to the next form if `[q1] = 1 and [q2] = 1 and [q3] = 1`. Although you will need to contact your site administrators to install this/enable for your project.